# Detect if object has overriden toString()

Tags: java, reflection, overriding

I'm receiving an Object and need to log it. Some of them have cusom `toString()` and then I'd like to use that, but some have none and I get something like `mightypork.rogue.bus.events.MouseMotionEvent@2d19587d`.

I'm looking for a way to dynamically (perhaps with reflection?) check if the incoming object has `toString()` overridden itself.

```
String objToString(Object o)
{
    if(???) {
        return o.toString();
    } else {
        // fallback method
        return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

}
```

Side note:

It's an event bus system, some classes can subscribe and then receive events based on implemented interfaces. I can't possibly require all clients to have toString(), plus I want to use this method for more than this one purpose.

Comment: You should check if the method is overridden http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821704/java-how-to-find-if-a-method-is-overridden-from-base-class

Comment: Well what would you do if they don't have a custom implementation anyway? You're not really supposed to do such a thing, it works around the purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: I don't care about principle of polymorfism, I want nice log output.

Comment: Then override `toString` yourself, that's what it's for! Don't you control your objects?

Comment: I'm don't want to add toString to everything; I don't have time for that. They aren't all data classes.

Comment: Anyway @Joffrey is right, so you will avoid the call of objToString and if in the future you will need the tostring of the object it's already here.

Comment: Which is all well and good, but it's far from clear how you could safely 'override' it if it didn't. The other issue is that to_string could have been overridden in a way that loses valuable information in terms of logging.

Comment: You can use `o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()` to get all the methods you declared in the class.

Comment: If the `toString()` is not among the methods returned by `getDeclaredMethods()` then its not overriden.

Comment: In logging I'd want the class name for definite and then the value might be an optional extra.

Comment: @MightyPork You could use [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29) to make the task a little less time consuming.

Comment: @MightyPork Do you mean you don't know what subset of your objects you want to log? Obviously not all classes need `toString` implementation, but not all of them need to be logged in console either.

Comment: How about reading the docs on Reflection? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()

Comment: @Joffrey It's an event bus system, some classes can subscribe and then receive events based on implemented interfaces. I can't possibly require all clients to have toString(), plus I want to use this method for more than this one purpose.

Comment: @MightyPork Ok that's why I asked "don't you control your objects?". So, since the answer is no, I then don't understand why you need more than the class name of the objects you get (in the case they do have a `toString`), because you don't know what the `String` will represent anyway.

Comment: I know I am late in the party, just a suggestion, if the function is not overridden, use Gson.toString()? Else do the same for everything, don't need to worry about the to String at all. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use the `Object getClass()` method, you can use the class and invoke the `getMethod().getDeclaringClass()` method. If it is `Object`, then it is not overridden. Otherwise, somewhere along the line is was overriden. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315445/how-to-quickly-determine-if-a-method-is-overridden-in-java)

Comment: Trying this approach at the moment.

Comment: I haven't actually tested it, so it must work, right @MightyPork?

Comment: Yes, it works pretty good. Basically `(o.getClass().getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass() != Object.class)` is the thing I needed.

Comment: `getDeclaredMethods()` only returns methods declared in the class and **not** inherited. Is not that easier to use that?

Comment: @GermannArlington No, what if we have class `A` which overrides `toString` and we have class `B extends A`. If we would check if `B` did overwrite `toString` it would say `false` where the goal to check if it is not the `toString` from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is silly a bit but u can try that:

```
    String objToString(Object o)
{
    if(!(o.toString().contains("@" + o.hashCode()))) {
        return o.toString();
    } else {
        // fallback method
        return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

}
```

or just something like that simplified version:

```
String objToString(Object o) {
  if (o.toString().equals(
      o.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(o.hashCode()))) {
    // fallback method
    return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
  } else {
    return o.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: could work, perhaps with a regex to be more precise, but there's got to be a cleaner way via reflection.

Comment: Yes, it is silly. You will exclude any `toString()` method that produces output which includes "@" in your suggested case and any other combination with any other substring

Comment: @GermannArlington Trivially extendable to `o.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(o.hashCode())` as per the docs.

Comment: @GermannArlington ha im writing straight from my head

Comment: @Duncan The point is that your own implementation of `toString()` may include this information and if you use the code above even with improved searchString it will be excluded. So the only feasible option  **is** using Reflection to check declared methods.

Comment: @GermannArlington If one checks for exactly `o.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(o.hashCode())` and no more, then the matter is moot. Either no override has occurred or the override has chosen to present exactly the same information.

Comment: +0 - it's an ugly hack, but a working one, as @Duncan already pointed out.

Comment: This is incredibly unreliable. Default `toString()` is, iirc, implementation specific, so this will break depending on the JDK implementation you're using. Use only as an *absolute last resort* and prefer @nimsson's answer first.

Answer (score 1):

Here to check if you have a toString method in your object :

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TemplateHelper {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int a = 3;
        try {
            objToString(a);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void objToString(Object object) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        Class c = object.getClass();
        Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if(method.getName().equals("toString")){
                System.out.println(method.getName()); //THERE IS toString in object
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this would work, but can be done cleaner.

Comment: A clean and full aproach of your problem : http://robsanheim.com/2005/12/08/using-reflection-to-determine-if-a-method-is-overloaded/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use reflection to figure it out. Find the `toString` method in the object you received using reflection. If it was declared in `java.lang.Object`, then use your own method.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Random;

public class ToStringUtils {
    public static String myToString(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return "null";
        if (overridesToString(o.getClass()))
            return o.toString();
        // Replacement for Object.toString()
        return o.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + System.identityHashCode(o);
    }

    public static boolean overridesToString(Class<?> clazz) {
        Method m;
        try {
            m = clazz.getMethod("toString");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // Can't be thrown since every class has a toString method through Object
            return false;
        }
        return (m.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class);
    }

    // Small demo
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myToString(new Integer(5)));
        System.out.println(myToString(new Random()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work correctly if parent class of current one overrides toString. But it's better then checking with regex as other suggestions

Comment: @BogdanMart It works with overridden methods in parent classes in the way that the OP asked. What/when do you think doesn't work with it?

Comment: I was wrong. I didn't noticed, that you check declaring class on fetched method. And I thought you are getting method from current class, not with inheritance. So nice, thanks.