# given an object how to know the overridden inherited methods

Tags: java, reflection

Given the following code:

```
class A{
    int i;
        int hashcode(){
            . . .
        }
}
```

Precisely, given an object `a` of `A` how can one say that `hashcode()` which inherited from `Object` class is overridden in the class `A`.

`a.getClass().getDeclaringClass()` is returning `Object`class. I want it to output `A`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315467/584862

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Note that we are not looking for overridden methods, but for overriding methods. Both have not the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```java
public static Set<Method> findOverridingMethods(Object o) {
    Set<Method> overridingMethods = new HashSet<Method>();
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        Class<?> current = clazz.getSuperclass();
        while (current != null) {
            try {
                current.getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                overridingMethods.add(method);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignore) {
            }
            current = current.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
    return overridingMethods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use the `Method` object obtained by using

```
getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hashCode").getDeclaringClass()
```

Comment: How can it work? Do you have any working example?

Comment: This **is** actually a working example.