# Detecting if hashcode and/or equals have been overriden (in ANY superclass)

Tags: java

Is there a way to detect if any super class of a class has overridden hashCode or equals?

### example

`D` extends `C` extends `B` extends `A` extends `Object`

`B` implements its own hashcode and equals

#### therefore I need a method that returns

- for `A` `false`
- for `B` `true`
- for `C` `true`
- for `D` `true`

is this possible?

### alternatively

if there is a solution that requires `A` to override `hashCode and equals` instead of `B` that is fine too. The main thing is just that I know the default `Object` hashcode and equals aren't being used

Comment: @Zong are you sure? I tried this (getMethod()) technique from a similar answer and it seems to only work if that class specifically overrides it, not a super class - please remove the marked as duplicate and close flag unless you are absolutely sure

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely certain, I think my answer is proof of that :)

Comment: If you don't believe the noted question is a duplicate, show the results you get from that method, and what you expect, because it's not clear how you think they would differ.

Comment: @Zong ok my apologies, my code (in my project) was not using 'getDeclaringClass()' so that is why I thought it only worked on the current class. Now I followed your code and fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the example from [How to quickly determine if a method is overridden in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315445/how-to-quickly-determine-if-a-method-is-overridden-in-java) and wrote:

```
class A extends Object {
    public boolean isHashCodeOverridden() throws Exception {
        return !this.getClass()
            .getMethod("hashCode")
            .getDeclaringClass()
            .equals(Object.class);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int hashCode() { return 0; }
}

class C extends B {}

class D extends C {}
```

Then

```
System.out.println(new A().isHashCodeOverridden());
System.out.println(new B().isHashCodeOverridden());
System.out.println(new C().isHashCodeOverridden());
System.out.println(new D().isHashCodeOverridden());
```

Prints

```
false
true
true
true
```

as expected.

Try it: https://ideone.com/StpSBt

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection and check if a method is declared in class and its super classes, like `A.class.getDeclaredMethods()` and you will know